# How to enumerate all locally declared script variables?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Is there a way to get **only** the locally declared variables in a powershell script?

In this snippit, I would want it to return only `myVar1`, `myVar2`, `anotherVar`:

```
$myVar1 = "myVar1"
$myVar2 = "myVar2"
$anotherVar = "anotherVar"
Get-Variable -Scope Script
```

But it instead returns a ton of other local script variables.

The problem I'm trying to solve, and maybe you can suggest another way, is that I have many Powershell scripts that have a bunch of misc variable constants declared at the top.

I want to export them all to disk (xml) for import later.

So to call `Get-Variable bla* | Export-Clixml vars.xml`, I need to know all of the variable names.

So is there a way I can like do

```
$allVars = {
    $myVar1 = "alex"
    $myVar2 = "iscool"
    $anotherVar = "thisisanotherVar"
}
Get-Variable allVars | Export-Clixml "C:\TEMP\AllVars.xml"
```

And then later `Import-Clixml .\AllVars.xml | %{ Set-Variable $_.Name $_.Value }` ?

So that the rest of the script could still use `$myVar1` etc without major changes to what is already written?

Comment: `ls variable:` should be ok?

Comment: It gets all sorts of other variables I wouldn't want to load, such a `PWD` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is there are more variables that are accessible in that scope beyond the ones you already declared. One thing you could do is get the list of variables *before* you declare yours. Get another copy of all the variables and compare the list to just get yours.

```
$before = Get-Variable -Scope Local
$r = "Stuff"
$after =  Get-Variable -Scope Local

# Get the differences
Compare-Object -Reference $current -Difference $more -Property Name -PassThru
```

The above should spit out names and simple values for your variables. If need be you should be able to easily send that down the pipe to Export-CliXML. If your variables are complicated you might need to change the `-depth` for more complicated objects.

**Caveat:** If you are changing some default variable values the above code currently would omit them since it is just looking for new names.

Also not sure if you can import them exactly in the same means as they were exported. This is largely dependent on your data types. For simple variables this would be just fine

> I need to know all of the variable names.

The only other way that I am aware of (I never really considered this) would be to change all of the variable to have a prefix like `my_` so then you could just have one line for export.

```
Get-Variable my_* | Export-Clixml vars.xml
```

Comment: If the scripts aren't calling each other, you don't need to record `$before`, you can just compare `-Scope 0` to `-Scope 1`. Of course that has its own problem in that it will catch modified variables too (even if they were not declared by any user script).

Comment: That's what I figured I would have to do. Is there a better method than the XML-Variable approach to store a bunch of constants for reuse? I have one script called `RefreshEnvironment` for example, and we have `Test1` and `Test2` servers, where the "function" of the script is identical, but `Test1` has different server names and same with `Test2`

Comment: @AlexKwitny XML is a better approach for complex variables and objects. It is more type aware. Else you could using CSV files but that would only be good for string and numbers.

Comment: @AlexKwitny: I happened to have need for a solution to this in my scripts. I settled on using one global variable (a hash table) exported from a module to contain the rest of the (considerable) configuration data. This hash contained only simple values and other nested hashes. Of course, I still use parameters to my cmdlets whenever that is more appropriate than the reference context, but using constantly repeated parameters for everything got old fast, even with splatting.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You could answer with your own approach. It sounds like OP has control and could choose to do that. It is also similar to the pseudo code example of the OP

Comment: @Matt: yes, but that's not an answer to the question as stated, even though that is itself a bit of an XY problem. Doing it this way definitely requires "major changes to what is written" (you need to put the hash everywhere); I was fine with that (I consider it a small price to pay for some modularity, which is never easy to come by in scripting languages).

Comment: @JeroenMostert You're right about the answer to question as written, but in theory, I could dump the variables to a Hashtable, then using something similar to `$hash.Keys | % { "key = $_ , value = " + $hash.Item($_) }` to get the `Key`=`VariableName` combined with `Set-Variable`, I could accomplish what I was originally wanting, yes?

Comment: @AlexKwitny: Almost. If your keys or values need escaping then dumping a string to a hash is much more painful -- I have *no idea* why there is no built-in cmdlet for it, since it means PowerShell lacks a simple serialization format (CliXml works as long as you don't want to peek inside, `ConvertTo/ConvertFrom-Json` do not roundtrip). I wrote such a function anyway for debugging purposes and you can find attempts online as well, but my scenario was originally only for easily importing these values from a file and changing them from the command line, not saving them back.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ah I only need to dump them to a file/hash one time. I could manually do it if needed. The plan is to eventually have the variables all filled from a file so that we can just copy the script that does the work & the variables file, then switch the variables file. Great info though thanks!